# Abrir apenas uma instância

Tags: javascript, popup

Eu estou com um problema, eu quero abrir uma janela com `window.open` em um chat, é assim, quando um usuário manda uma mensagem, o painel principal recebe a mensagem pelo `socket` usando `websocket.onmessage`, daí abre um modal para a outra pessoa ver que alguém enviou esta mensagem, e no modal tem um evento `onclick` que abre uma janela usando `window.open`, até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quero abrir este `window` que é atribuído uma `ID` apenas uma vez, ou seja, se a outra pessoa enviar uma nova mensagem eu checo se a janela de `ID` correspondente já está aberta, pra não ficar mostrando a mensagem direto mesmo já estando com a janela de bate papo aberta.

Então criei a seguinte função:

```
var winPop = false;

    function OpenWindow(msgdoc,url,idc){
      if(winPop && !winPop.closed){  //checka se a janela já está aberta
        winPop.focus();
      } else{
        $("#chattext").text(msgdoc);
        $("#cli").trigger('click');

        //Abre a janela quando o usuário clicar no modal
        $("#chat").click(function(){
            $(this).hide("slow");
            winPop = window.open(url,"_blank",+idc+',scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
        });

      }
    }
```

Aí no `socket` fiz o seguinte:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
  var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); //Recebe os dados enviados pelo socket PHP
  var type = msg.type; //Recebe o Tipo de mensagem
  var umsg = msg.message; //Recebe Mensagem
  var de_id = msg.de_id; //Recebe de_id
  var url = 'http://siteta.com/chat/index.php?id='+de_id+'&nome='+uname+'&port=8080';
            OpenWindow(umsg,url,de_id);
}
```

Ou seja, sempre que receber uma nova mensagem, ele irá checar se a janela já está aberta, se não estiver, ele mostrará o modal, caso contrário não mostrará nada.

O Problema é que, se o usuário do outro lado, enviar por exemplo 5 mensagens, ou seja, a função vai ser chamada 5 vezes, o modal vai ser mostrado normalmente, mas ao clicar nele, irá abrir 5 janelas iguais, mas eu só quero que abra apenas uma janela, mesmo que o usuário envie 10 mensagens, fazendo a função se executar 10 vezes, ao clicar no modal abra apenas 1 PopUp e não 10 como está ocorrendo, é como se ficasse em cache sei lá.

Comment: E se você fizesse uma IF antes de abrir a popup? Tipo comparar se a ID recebida já está aberta...

Comment: Mas já tem isso na função `OpenWindow`, e mesmo assim abre um monte da janelas.

Comment: E se você declarar `winPop = true;` quando a janela abrir pela primeira vez já que você declarou ela `false` antes?

Comment: Já sim, declarei ela como `false` e dentro do `else` coloquei-a como `true`, aí o modal só abriu uma vez, mesmo que o outro usuário enviasse mais mensagens, o modal não atualizava as mensagens, mas ao clicar pra abrir o popup, ele abria um número `X` de janelas, que era equivalente ao número de mensagens enviadas. ou seja, não deu certo também!

Comment: É como se tivesse dando um loop na função de acordo com o número de mensagens.

Comment: é isso! e não consigo pensar numa solução!

Comment: Veja se dá certo tirando o `"_blank",` do popup

Comment: Que eu saiba a sintaxe para abrir popup com window.open é (url,nome_da_janela,atributos)... Acho que o "_blank" sobrou aí..

Comment: Também pensei que fosse... mas não é! quando tiro o "_blank", a janela abre em uma nova guia, e não em popup.

Comment: Em vez de +idc+', coloca só o idc e coloca uma aspas simples depois da vírgula , assim:  `winPop = window.open(url,"_blank",idc,'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');`
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que o método `window.open` deve receber os seguintes parâmetros:

```
window.open(url,nome_da_janela,atributos);
```

Onde:

- **url:** URL da página a ser carregada na janela.
- **nome_da_janela:** um nome qualquer para identificar a janela.
- **atributos:** tamanho, posição da janela etc...

Para setar a janela com o mesmo `id` vindo como parâmetro da função, evitando abrir novas janelas para o mesmo `id`, o correto seria:

```
winPop = window.open(url,idc,'scrollbars=1,menubar=0,resizable=1,width=850,height=500');
```